# initdb: error: directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata" exists but is not empty

Tags: database, postgresql, kubernetes-pvc

I ended up with this logs in my postgres container running in kubernetes. How do I fix this?

> The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user
> "postgres".
>
> │ This user must also own the server process.
> │
>
> │ The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
> │
>
> │ The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
> │
>
> │ The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
> │
>
> │ Data page checksums are disabled.
> │
>
> │ initdb: error: directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata" exists
> but is not empty
> │
>
> │ If you want to create a new database system, either remove or empty
> │
>
> │ the directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata" or run initdb
> │
>
> │ with an argument other than "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata".   ```

Here is variable and volumemount:

```
- name: PGDATA
  value: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
volumeMounts:
- mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
  name: postgres-database
```

The pod is now crashed and I am trying to put in sleep and recover it. I do not want to loose any data

Comment: The error is saying you are trying to create a new Postgres cluster via `initdb` in a directory that already contains files. Those files could be anything, but `initdb` will not create a new cluster in that case.  If you don't need a new cluster don't run `initdb`. For more information read [initdb](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-initdb.html).